# SQL left join not getting result as expected

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables as follows:

**tableA**

```
pat_id   name   user_id

1     sam       1
2     jose      1
3     sandra    2
```

**tableB**

```
    id      pat_id  pat-main_name

    1           1    MR0001
    2           3    MR0005
```

I am expecting the result as follows:

```
pat_id   name   user_id pat-main_name

1     sam       1    MR0001
2     jose      1
```

I have `user_id = 1`

What I did is as follows:

```
SELECT tableA.pat_id,tableA.name,tableA.user_id,tableB.pat-main_name
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB
where tableA.pat_id = tableB.pat_id AND tableA.user_id;
```

and I am getting result as:

```
pat_id   name   user_id pat-main_name

1     sam       1    MR0001
2     jose      1
3     Sandra    2
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is this? `where tableA.pat_id = tableB.pat_id AND tableA.user_id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left join`

```
SELECT tableA.pat_id,tableA.name,tableA.user_id,tableB.pat-main_name
FROM tableB left join tableA
ON tableB.pat_id = tableA.pat_id
WHERE tableA.user_id=1
```

Comment: buddy it will return all detials I need result related to user_id 1 only. please check my expected result!!

Comment: SELECT tableA.pat_id,tableA.name,tableA.user_id,tableB.pat-main_name
FROM tableB JOIN tableA
ON tableB.pat_id = tableA.pat_id
WHERE tableA.user_id=1

Comment: @Rahautos, change to left join and that will do it

Comment: @Rahautos if I use join then I do not get the second column in that tableB.pat-main_name is blank . I need that also in my result. hope you understand!!

Comment: SELECT tableA.pat_id,tableA.name,tableA.user_id,tableB.pat-main_name
FROM tableB left join tableA
ON tableB.pat_id = tableA.pat_id
WHERE tableA.user_id=1 @Santhucool

Answer (score 1):

This query properly joins the 2 tables:

```
SELECT tableA.pat_id
    ,tableA.name
    ,tableA.user_id
    ,tableB.`pat-main_name`
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.pat_id = tableB.pat_id;
```

Your original query was sort of mixing the old syntax and the newer ANSI syntax which should be preferred:

- old syntax = FROM a, b WHERE a.x = b.x...
- new ANSI = ... JOIN ON a.x = b.x...

You can restrict the output by adding a WHERE clause such as `WHERE tableA.user_id = 1` .

It will give this output:

```
1     sam       1    MR0001
2     jose      1
3     Sandra    2    NULL
```

Or with a WHERE clause `tableA.user_id = 1`:

```
1     sam       1    MR0001
2     jose      1
```

Comment: I do not want last record . I mean user_id=1. I do not want last column. otherwise your query is right

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT 
 tableA.pat_id, tableA.name, tableA.user_id,
 tableB.`pat-main_name`
FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON tablea.pat_id = tableb.pat_id
Where tablea.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write query as follow:

```
 SELECT `t`.`name`, 
   `t1`.`pat_id`, 
   `t1`.`pat-main_name` 
    FROM tableA AS t LEFT JOIN tableB AS t1 ON `t`.`pat_id` = `t1`.`pat_id`
```